# How is this lower bound of the dimension of a homogeneous algebraic variety reached?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm hoping to see how the following bound is reached.

For an algebraic variety $V\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ over some field $F$, one defines $\dim V=\operatorname{trdeg}(F(x)/F)$ for a generic point $(x)$ of $V$. Also, I denote by $V(f_1,\dots,f_m)$ the set of zeroes in $\mathbb{A}^n$  of some homogeneous forms $f_i$.

All right, so $V:=V(f_1,\dots,f_m)$ is a homogeneous algebraic variety. How does it follow that the dimension of $V$ is bounded below by $n-m$? That is, why is $\dim V\geq n-m$? Thank you.

Comment: It really boils down to Krull's principal ideal theorem.  See Prop 7.1 in Hartshorne, page 48.

Comment: Dear @Parsa, you mean generalization of Krull's theorem since there are no principal ideals in sight here. Moreover the part describing the dimension of $V$ in terms of the transcendence degree of the field of rational functions on $V$ has nothing to do with Krull's principal ideal theorem and yet has to be taken care of before answering Waldott's question (the reference you give doesn't answer it) .

Answer (score 3):

There are two different ingredients  to the solution of your problem.
Consider  a finitely generated domain $A$ over a field $k$, and its associated variety $V= Spec (A)$

I) The Krull dimension of $V$ is equal to the transcendence degree of its field of rational functions: 
 $$\text {dim }(V) =\text {trdeg} _k(\text {Frac }(A))$$

II) If $V\subset \mathbb A_k^n$ is given by a prime ideal $\mathfrak p=(f_1,...,f_m)\subset  k[T_1,...,T_n]$ generated by $m$ polynomials , that is $V=Spec(A)=Spec(k[T_1,...,T_n]/(f_1,...,f_m))$, then
$$       \text {dim }(V)\geq n-m             $$

**Notes**
1) You will find the proof of I) in Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*, Ch.13, §1, Theorem A.
And II) is Theorem 10.2 of the same book.

2) There is no need to suppose thar the $f_i$'s are homogeneous in II)

3) If $\text {dim }(V)= n-m $, the variety $V$ is said to be a scheme-theoretic complete intersection.
Beware that this equality is not true in general: the variety    $V \subset \mathbb A^3_k$ given parametrically by $x=t^3, y=t^4, z=t^5$ is of dimension $1$ but  has  an ideal $I(V)=\mathfrak p\subset k[T_1,T_2,T_3 ]$  which  *cannot* be generated by $ 3-1=2$ generators.

Comment: Thank you for these references Georges! Much appreciated.